# Can't SSH to remote server when using public key - Could not establish connection

Tags: visual-studio-code

I added my EC2 instance to the configuration file:

```
Host EC2-Instance
HostName 12.12.12.12
User ec2user
Port 22
IdentityFile C:\Users\myuser\Documents\ec2_instance.ppk
```

But I still get "Could not establish connection" error.
In the vscode terminal I see "Permission denied (publickey)"

The same key works when using PuTTy to connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: In VSCode, you need to use another format for the key - the OpenSSH format, and not PPK.

In order to do that, I used PuTTYGen to convert the `.ppk` file to an OpenSSH compatible key.

I opened PuTTYGen, then clicked on "Load" in the main window. I selected the `.ppk` file. After that, I clicked on "Conversions" tab in the menu, and clicked "Export OpenSSH Key". I used no password but you can secure it with a password before.

Then it opens the save window where you need to give your file a name. I just gave it "myopensshkey" and saved.

The file was saved in the folder and I then added it to the config file in VS Code (The file has no extension):

```
Host EC2-Instance
HostName 12.12.12.12
User ec2user
Port 22
IdentityFile C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myopensshkey
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's generally because VSCode literally uses OpenSSH to make the connection (and that file is the OpenSSH config – not VSCode config).